# how to plot a sequence of numbers (not co-ordinates as such) using pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have a data file containing a sequence of numbers, to be plotted against integers starting from 1. So the x co-ordinate is the row number of the data in the file. How to plot this data using pgfplots?

UPDATE1: my data file looks like this

```
%cmc curve of nist14G21600V0P8T1sumFuse.bin

73.037

75.2963

76.7407

77.8889

79.1111

79.8519

80.3333

80.7407

81.0741

81.4444
```

UPDATE 2:

When the above data is plotted using the command

```
\addplot  table [x expr=\coordindex + 1,y index=0]{datafile.txt};
```

the x axis does not start with 1. It starts with 0. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the new request of @suresh:

`pgfplots` can read a data file and plot the contents. To use a special column of the data file you can use `y index` for the y values. The first column has the index `0`. For the x axis you can use `\coordindex` started by `0`. To start at `1` you can use `\coordindex+1`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{datafile.dat}
%cmc curve of nist14G21600V0P8T1sumFuse.bin

73.037

75.2963

76.7407

77.8889

79.1111

79.8519

80.3333

80.7407

81.0741

81.4444
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[only marks,] table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y index=0] {datafile.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**ORIGINAL**

You can use the option `x expr=\coordindex`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{datafile.dat}
Y-Value
2
5
8
1
5
7
6
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
\addplot +[only marks] table[x expr=\coordindex,y=Y-Value] {datafile.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for the reply. But I face some other issues now. First of all my file does not have a column name. What it has is a bunch of lines starting with % character followed by data line by line. Basically I was using gnuplot so far and the file is generated with gnuplot in mind. I tried giving just table[x expr = \coordindex]{datafilename} but it gave me an error message saying that Sorry, the requested column number '1' in table 'datafilename' does not exist!? So what to do now?

Comment: @suresh: Nice information. Please add this information with a small example file to your question.

Comment: I have just given the sample datafile. I tried adding header=false, but didn't help either.

Comment: @suresh: I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks it helped, but two more questions. I get an error message saying that `! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/skip first n' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.` I checked the log file and found out that the versions are: Package: pgf 2008/01/15 v2.10 (rcs-revision 1.12),pgfplots 2010/07/14 Version 1.4.1. So are  you using a newer version? My second question is: cant pgfplots by default ignore lines starting with '%'. I remember to have read somewhere that lines starting with % are ignored.

Comment: Great! I just removed the `skip first n` part, its working fine. Thank you. btw, I also want to tell you that I somehow like the pgf output than what I used to get with gnuplot. No offense to gnuplot lovers out there - which I was. :)

Comment: Hey one more problem: My x axis starts from 0 only even though my plot line is like this: `\addplot  table [x expr=\coordindex + 1,y index=0]{datafile.txt};` What to do?

Comment: @suresh: set the option at the `axis` environment to `xmin=1`

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2755/discussion-between-suresh-and-marco-daniel)

Comment: But again there is another problem. The x-axis label starts with nothing. Please note that I have 2700 data points. Earlier the starting x label was 0 which I didnt want. Now the starting xlabel is 500. I want it to be 1, 500,100 etc.