# How do I plot multiple iterative functions (or recursive sequences) on one graph with TikZ?

Tags: tikz-pgf, plot

I'm trying to plot several (4) numerical sequences in TikZ.

Each of these sequences should be obtained by iterating the following function,

```
a*x*(1-x)
```

where `a` is a parameter that varies across the four sequences.

I want it to look like the one below, where the index represents the iteration number, and s is the value of said iteration:

[image]

Thanks to anyone who can help me.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. The easiest solution would most probably be, when you calculate the data externally and store the results in a data file which can then be used to plot the data, e.g. using the [PGFPlots](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgfplots) package. You will find plenty of examples here when you search for the tag [pgfplots](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pgfplots).

Comment: Have a look at what `foreach` does in Ti_k_Z. It pretty much covers your case: Something along the lines of `\foreach \a in {0,0.1,…,1} {\draw plot (\x,\a*(1-\x));}` should do it. (Not tested, just an idea)

Comment: Do you mean you want to draw [the cobweb plot for the logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:LogisticCobwebChaos.gif) ?

Comment: So I'm looking for a way to plot the Logistic equation, and show various results when a varies between 0 and 4. I have already used cobweb plots, so in this case I am simply looking for a graph with multiple iterative functions on it, where y=a*x*(1-x), and x is the fixed initial starting point.

Comment: I don't understand if you just want to plot some simple functions (in which case, just use `pgfplots`), or if there is something special you are trying to do ?

Comment: I am fairly new to Latex, and have been assigned a project in which I have to demonstrate my new skills etc, and I'm trying to show that when a=2, for example, the function tends to 0.667, and when a=3, it tends to 0.75. It might not help that someone edited my question header to something totally incorrect, sigh. It's correct now.

Comment: This is not an iterative function, you want to plot things one by one

Comment: It is a population growth model equation, so it needs to modelled iteratively.

Comment: Again, this is just a parametric curve. Not an iterative function. If you want a predator prey equation that's a completely different ball game. And it is called a recursive plot

Comment: Is [my answer below](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/375877/116936) what you need, or do you want something else ?

Comment: Hi marsupilam, thanks for taking the time to plot those graphs but I must not be explaining myself very well, apologies. I will add a png file to my initial question of the sort of graph I am looking for. It was generated in R Studio, but I want to replicate it, along with others, on one tikz picture graph.

Comment: Maybe you can add the formula as given to R so that we can better understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Huang_d Aha ! I'm not the only one to be quite perplexed as to what OP is talking about, then !

Comment: @marsupilam, no you are not. I also don't have a good idea what OP (exactly) wants. Assuming that it is not an easy equation that OP wants to solve, I still think my initial statement given as first comment is the best: Create a data file with an external program an "just" plot then these data with PGFPlots ...

Answer (score 1):

## Second attempt

This is one way to plot sequences in pgfplots.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{datafile.dat}
u v
0.200000 0.200000
0.320000 0.480000
0.435200 0.748800
0.491602 0.564296
0.499859 0.737598
0.500000 0.580641
0.500000 0.730491
0.500000 0.590622
0.500000 0.725363
0.500000 0.597634
0.500000 0.721403
0.500000 0.602943
0.500000 0.718208
0.500000 0.607155
0.500000 0.715553
0.500000 0.610610
0.500000 0.713296
0.500000 0.613514
0.500000 0.711343
0.500000 0.616002
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}
  [
    xmin=0,
    ymin=0,
    height=15cm,
    axis x line = bottom,
    axis y line = left,
    enlarge y limits={value=0.3,upper},
  ]
\addplot +[only marks,] table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y index=0] {datafile.dat};
\addplot +[only marks,] table[x expr=\coordindex+1,y index=1] {datafile.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## First attempt

I think it would be faster if I just answer, instead of debating...

Then you can tell us if this is what you need.

### The output

[image]

### The code

```
\documentclass[12pt,tikz,border=0pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}
    [
      domain = 0:1,
      axis lines = center,
    ]

    \foreach \a in {.2,.5, 1, 2}
    {
      \addplot+[mark=none] {\a*x*(1-x)};
    }

  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not what I am looking for, unfortunately! Appreciate the time and effort to help though.

Comment: @LukeJeeves Like this, then ? I mostly copy-paste from [Marco Daniel's answer here.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47775/116936)

Comment: Yes! This is what I was looking for! Thank you kindly for your help, not only am I new to Latex, but also to StackExchange! Much appreciated.

Comment: You should really have phrased your question differently. I will try to fix your question for future readers.

Comment: apologies, thanks for your understanding and time.